# How to roll back my change in Git?

Tags: git, feature-branch

I committed change `A` into my `feature branch`.
All good so I merged to `Develop`.
Two other merges `B` & `C`, are done to `Develop` from other `feature branches`.

A problem comes up with my change so I have to roll back.

**Q1. What should I do?**

I check out an old version of `Develop` (the most recent before A), copy it off, `revert` back to head, then paste over.

Q2. I was hoping to re-apply changes `B` & `C` but no diff so can't.
Anything I can do to reapply `B` & `C`? Or was the problem unfixable at `Q1`?

Comment: do the other 2 merges touch the same files/lines as your merge? if not, you can probably just `git revert commit^..range`

Comment: I’d suggest reset develop pre branchA merge and then re-merge B and C.

Comment: Read the supplied answer to the duplicate question and then use `git cherry-pick` if you need to pick specific commits